# How can I use :nth-child() to select every other <div> within ALL children?

Tags: html, css, comments, css-selectors

I'm working on a comments system, and I need to have every other child `<div>` (even children of the first children) be selected with CSS.

For example, lets say I have this markup (omitting unneeded closing tags just for simplicity):

```
 <body>
<div class="comment">
    <div class="comment"/>
    <p class="something else"/>
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment"/>
        <div class="comment"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment"/>
<div class="comment"/>
</body>
```

How can I select **every other** `<div>` within the body (excluding `<p>`)?

What I basically want is for it to turn out like this:

(Two stars is even, one star is odd, regular is neither)

```
 <body>
    **<div class="comment">**
        *<div class="comment"/>*
        <p class="something else"/>
        **<div class="comment">**
            *<div class="comment"/>*
            **<div class="comment"/>**
        </div>
    </div>
    *<div class="comment"/>*
    **<div class="comment"/>**
    </body>
```

I need it to walk through every other `<div>` in order, applying the styles.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You will need `nth-of-type` as opposed to `nth-child` if you want to select `div` elements and not `p` elements.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I think the OP wants to select **nested** `div`s as well and then style all of them by `odd`/`even` which is not possible even by `nth-of-type` pseudo-class.

Comment: @HashemQolami I know that he wants to select nested elements. Regardless, my point still stands, `nth-of-type` should be used because of the varying elements types.

Comment: @HashemQolami That is correct. Are you saying there is basically no way to do this? If so, I will have to add some custom functions to the CMS I'm using. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JoshCrozier Interesting. I shall check out nth-of-type.

Comment: @Brian did you delete your answer? I thought you were on to something with that JQuery code! :)

Comment: I am still working on it :) I have a cool idea Im trying to work out

Comment: @Blue_Dragon360 after 2h lost of this issue... please help us to help you, next time avoid simplification where it's not needed, explain **in detail** your problem and what you need.

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot select the nth occurrence of an element across the document using just CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[- Advanced demo with multiThread colored comments](http://jsbin.com/guvat/19/edit)**
**[- Simple demo](http://jsbin.com/guvat/13/edit)**

Ugh this took a while just to understand from OP that *"even"* / *"odd"* are actually **not the CSS's** `even` and `odd` but the **index of appearance** of a `.comment` div, (nested or not).

**CSS**? Almost impossible if not even impossible. (possible only with nesting too much styles to cover all possibilities)

With **jQuery** simply like:

```
$('.comment').addClass(function(i){
  return i%2 ? "odd" : "even";
});
```

where `i` represents the Element's Array Index position (0,1,2,3...) of  that `.comment` element jquery collected on it's way. Now if `i reminder 2` returns `0` add the `"even"` class, else `:` add the `"odd"` class to that element.

**CSS:**

```
div.comment{
  /* Common styles */
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.even { background:blue; } /* jQ Index: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8... */
.odd  { background:red;  } /* jQ Index: ...1, 3, 5, 7... */
```