# Indiscriminate adding alternating classes to angular recursive template

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, recursion, nested

Here is my recursive template, Thank you [Brendan Owens](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/).

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <div class="expanded row">
        <div class="medium-1 columns author"><img ng-if="data.isAnon || !user.isAdmin" src="https://people.sap.com/avatar/santanu.kargupta" />
            <img ng-if="!data.isAnon && user.isAdmin" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <p ng-if="!data.isAnon" class="author-name">{{ data.author }}
                <br class="show-for-medium-only">
                <span class="subtext">&middot;&nbsp;{{ data.createdAt | date : "MMMM dd, yyyy &middot; HH:mm:ss a" }}</span>
            </p>
            <p ng-if="data.isAnon">Anonymous
                <br class="show-for-medium-only">
                <span class="subtext">&middot;&nbsp;{{ data.createdAt | date : "MMMM dd, yyyy &middot; HH:mm:ss a" }}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <p ng-bind-html="data.content"></p>
        <div class="medium-offset-1" id="add-reply">
            <a href="#" ng-click="showCommentCreate(data); $event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault()"><img src="../assets/img/reply.svg" alt="">&nbsp;Add Reply</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content-divider"></div>
        <div class="comment" ng-repeat="data in data.comments" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</script>
<div class="comment" ng-repeat=" data in post.comments " ng-include=" 'tree_item_renderer.html' "></div>
```

The idea is that I have a post **tree object structure** displaying comments and the comments within them, so on and so forth. Now I'm down to the styling of this these elements *(Using Foundation 6)*. I have tried using `ng-odd` & `ng-even` as I usually do on all of my angular projects, but an issue arises due to the nested nature of my data. Searching high and low for a solution: I stumbled across some simple jquery I thought would solve the problem: [How can I use :nth-child() to select every other <div> within ALL children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715302/how-can-i-use-nth-child-to-select-every-other-div-within-all-children). I thought would help but angular is very particular about who it plays with. **Meaning it wanted to play alone** haha. Either way, I have run out of ideas and spaghetti to throw at the wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated :). Thank you in advanced!

**EDIT:** Never actually asked my question: is there a way in angular to add a class alternator indiscriminate of depth in the nest. Maybe base it's alternation off of the value the repeat puts out

*I worded this horribly sorry. X(*

Comment: @rolspace thanks for the edit. :)

Comment: this directive fixed it: 

`app.directive("altRows", function() {
  return function (scope, element, attrs){
   scope.$watch('posts', function(value){
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('.post-root').each(function(index, root){
      $(root).find('.post-comment').addClass(function(i){
       return i%2 ? "odd" : "even";
      });
     });
    }, 100);
   });
  };
 });`